# Chat message container shape in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I make this container shape for my chat log? in Flutter.

[image]

My problem is the bottom-right corner of the container.

Should i use CustomPainter? (Im not that good in this)

Is there a special Container() box which i can use?

Because if you look closely it also has some curves on the triangle-ish corner.

Thanks you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

You build it using the `CustomClipper` class and `CustomPaint`. You can read more about CustomClipper from the [Documentary](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomClipper-class.html) and theres a nicely explained document on [Medium](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-custom-clipper-28c6d380fdd6).

You can also use the [flutter_custom_clippers](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers) package as a guideline on how to use CustomClipper. They have great examples.

Alternatively, you can just use the [flutter_chat_bubble](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_chat_bubble) package that already have it all designed and ready to use

Answer (score 0):

you can use [flutter_custom_clippers](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers)
With this package, you get different custom shapes
I hope this package can help you